# how to call php function in loop $vmail = new verifyEmail(); in loop

Tags: php

I run this script but not work. 
I think this is a "$vmail = new verifyEmail();" problem 
this class not work in loop.

```
foreach ($queu_mails as $queu_mails_a) {
  $vmail = new verifyEmail();

  if ($vmail->check($db_mail)) {} else {

      $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `blacklist` (`id`, `mail`, `reason`) VALUES (NULL, '$db_mail', 'SMTP REJECT');");
      continue;
  }

  unset($vmail);
}
```

How to fix this code? 
how to change it?

Comment: What does 'not work' mean? What does it do? What is it supposed to do? Do you get a blank screen? An error?

Comment: on my server error reporting is disabled. I show only blank screen. This is a email SMTP validation class.